# Couldnot find ABI from solc.compile response web3.js

Tags: solidity, web3js, nodejs

I am very new to ethereum and was trying to get the bytecode and ABI from solc.compile using web3js but couldnot find the ABI. I got the bytecode. I saved the json response to files and Could only get these outputs.

1. assembly.json
2. bytecode.json
3. deployedBytecode.json
4. gasEstimates.json
5. legacyAssembly.json
6. methodIdentifiers.json

Here is my code:

```
const inboxPath = path.resolve(__dirname,'contracts','inbox.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(inboxPath,'utf8');

// build path
const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'compiled');


/**
 * the new version only supports standard JSON in and out
 * @type {{settings: {outputSelection: {"*": {"*": string[]}}}, sources: {"inbox.sol": {content: string}}, language: string}}
 */
const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'inbox.sol':{
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings:{
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['evm', 'bytecode'],
            },
        },
    },
};

async function compile() {
    const response = await solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input));

    const output = await JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

    const contracts = output.contracts['inbox.sol']["Inbox"].evm;

    const compiledResults = JSON.parse(response)["contracts"]["inbox.sol"]["Inbox"]["evm"];

    for (const contractName in contracts) {
        fs.writeFileSync(`${buildPath}/${contractName}.json`, JSON.stringify(contracts[contractName]))
    }
}

compile().then();
```

Here is the versions of web3js, solidity and other necessary packages i am using:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ganache-cli": "^6.12.2",
    "mocha": "^9.2.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.11",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.26"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution. I forgot to add abi on the output selection. Here is the corrected input variable.

```
const input = {
    language: 'Solidity',
    sources: {
        'inbox.sol':{
            content: source,
        },
    },
    settings:{
        outputSelection: {
            '*': {
                '*': ['evm', 'bytecode', 'abi'],
                // use * to get all the fields
                // '*': ["*"]
            },
        },
    },
};
```